# Using Wordpress Video Shortcode, how can I control playback via JS?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video

I am building a WordPress site and have embedded a video using WP's built in video-short code. My goal is to cause the video to auto play or not, dependent on the presence of a cookie. WP appears to use MediaElement.js.

In JS I have the cookie detection sorted, but no matter what I try I can't figure out how to trigger the video to play. I am not sure if I'm just not selecting the correct element, but I'm currently trying:

```
jQuery(".mejs-video").play();
```

The console shows error: "`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...)`.play is not a function"

How can I select and trigger the video generated by the shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution for myself like this :

```
$('.mejs-play button').click(); // Play
$('.mejs-pause button').click(); // Pause
```

I dont think it's the best solution (video API will be the best), but it work :)